# How to enable post method on Server 2003 IIS 6? HTTP Error 405

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6

I'm programming an Android application that read an XML file that sits on my server.
I'm using POST method in order to simply get the content of the XML (or any other file for that matter) using simple POST and RESPONSE methods.

```
// java code
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(XML_FILE);
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
```

it works fine on one of my linux servers but when I tried on my Windows 2003 IIS 6 server I get a

> HTTP Error 405 - The HTTP verb used to access this page is not
>   allowed.
> Internet Information Services (IIS)

I tried to add

```
<protocols>
      <add name="HttpGet"/>
      <add name="HttpPost"/>
</protocols>
```

to my web.config file but the results are the same.

I think the problem is that POST methods are disabled by defualt by I cant figure out how to enable them. do you think thats really is my problem? if so, how to I enable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally this means that you are trying to POST to a page that only has a static handler (like a `.html` file).

You need to ensure that your ISAPI plugin for the language you're posting to (`.net` or `php` or whatever) needs to be set up correctly and enabled.

Comment: can you elaborate on this? where do I need to look exactly? and i'm posting directly to the xml file.

Comment: @Joe - you can't post to an XML file, because IIS has no idea how to deal with that. An XML file is a static handler. You need to have something in the middle to do the translation from a web request to the XML file. As to how to do this, I'm afraid that's not something I can help with as it depends entirely on your programming language, and what you're trying to do.

Comment: well.. it's not really the POST action it is more of the RESPONSE.. because if you post to a webpage (any web page) where it allows to receive post methods then you get the entire page in the RESPONSE. therefor you can post a blank post to an XML file and get it as is. just like you can view it on the browser..

Comment: Ohh ok I only just saw your code snippet at the top (not sure how I missed that?), you should just be using HTTP GET, because POST with a blank POST is much the same. Obviously the Linux server you were testing it against wasn't as strict about the verbs you can use

Comment: at first I wasn't sure whether I should use get or post .. I figured it is more "standard" to use post since it seemed funny to me to use GET for an entire file.. do you think it is legit (using GET)? would I encounter any restriction or problems with it?

Comment: @Joe - GET is the absolute standard for fetching files. 99% of what you do on the web is GET, and downloading of files is almost always GET. The only time you don't use GET for downloading files is when you're doing something tricky, like rapidshare or one of those downloading sites.